# How do I get rid of my orphan MS Excel process from MS Access VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access, process, vba

I'm exporting an MS Access query to a template, doing some formatting, and then saving the template as a new name. When this is all done, I have an orphan MS Excel process that is interfering when the function is called again. I'm thinking this is either a problem with how I'm using ranges or a problem with my cleanup at the end.

Also I'm a novice coder so if anyone has any tips and tricks that I can take advantage of to make this better I'm always receptive.

Updated code after Andre's comments
Updated code after Rory's comments

```
Public Function OpenOrders(strSupplier As String)

'Excel file variables
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlsLRow As Long
Dim xlsLCol As Long

'Access variables
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

'Set up access objects
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryOpenOrderReport WHERE [Supplier Cd] = '" & strSupplier & "';"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

'Set up excel connection
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Open Order Template.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
xlapp.Visible = True

'Make sure the form is clear
xlsLRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
xlsLCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns(ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(xlsLRow, xlsLCol)).ClearContents

'Copy recordset to worksheet
ws.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close

'Copy formats down and autofit
xlsLRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
xlsLCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns(ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
xlapp.CutCopyMode = False
ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(2, xlsLCol)).Copy
ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, 1), ws.Cells(xlsLRow, xlsLCol)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
ws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

'Clean up
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set ws = Nothing
wb.SaveAs Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Open Orders\" & strSupplier & ".xlsx"
wb.Close True
Set wb = Nothing
xlapp.Quit
Set xlapp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I've had an orphan in the past when there was an invisible dialog asking me if I wanted to save changes; I discovered that after setting visible to true.

Answer (score 3):

**All** of your `Cells` calls need to be changed to `ws.Cells`. That is what is causing your orphaned process.

Comment: This solved the issue of the orphan process interfering with future function calls but I'm still getting orphan processes that pile up. Code updated.

Comment: Add an `xlapp.visible = true` at the start and see if there's anything preventing the app quitting at the end. Also you can populate the sheet a *lot* faster using just `ws.Cells(2, 1).Copyfromrecordset rs`

Comment: CopyFromRecordset just blew my mind, thank you. I added xlapp.Visible = true and it opens, I see it paste, and it closes. The process is still out there. Thanks a lot for your help so far. Code updated. What are your thoughts on wb.Close = true, strSupplier? I thought there might be a template and strSupplier sheet out there somehow.

Comment: Just to check - you do have a reference to Excel set in your Access project?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library, yes

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you still have an active reference to `ws` when doing the clean up, which prevents Excel from quitting.

I suggest doing it in this order:

```
'Clean up
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set ws = Nothing
wb.Close True, strSupplier
Set wb = Nothing
xlapp.Quit
Set xlapp = Nothing
```

---

`ws.Range("A2", "XFD1048576").ClearContents` seems a little radical :) - you can use `.UsedRange` for that.

---

An additional note:

After opening a recordset, you can never be in a situation where `rs.EOF` is False, but `rs.BOF` is True. So it is not necessary to test for `rs.BOF`.

With changing the loop to `Do While`, the `If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then` becomes superfluous:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
Do While Not rs.EOF 
    ' ...
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: I understood and implemented your change to my cleanup but I'm still getting a process open. I knew someone was going to say something about my method of clearing the form! I wanted to keep the header rows so I used my methods of getting the last row and last column to change that, making it a little more conservative. I also took your change to looping through the recordset, that'll save me a bunch of lines across many methods, thank you! Code updated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be extremely specific with objects of Excel, opening them and closing in reverse order. Here's a skeleton that works:

```
 Dim xls     As Excel.Application
 Dim wkb     As Excel.Workbook
 Dim wks     As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim rng     As Excel.Range

 Set xls = New Excel.Application
 Set wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open("c:\test\workbook1.xlsx")
 Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(1)
 Set rng = wks.<somerange>  ' Cells or whatever.

 ' Do stuff.

 ' Clean up.
 Set rng = Nothing

 wks.Name = "My New Name"
 wkb.Close True

 Set wks = Nothing
 Set wkb = Nothing

 xls.Quit

 Set xls = Nothing
```

Don't ever use wkb.Sheets for a WorkSheet.

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me either out of MS Access. I still have a process open after it's done.

Comment: Then probably something else is going on ... can't tell without code.

Comment: I updated my code in the original post. The one thing I've taken from you is to use wb.Worksheets(1).

Comment: Well, you are not cleaning up in exactly the same sequence. Also, try specifically to set and remove the ranges (or just comment out all the range stuff as an first attempt).

Comment: I commented out all the range stuff and the process is still open so it must be with cleaning up. I'm a little confused on that. The block that I have as "Set up excel connection" goes xlapp, wb, ws and then my cleanup goes ws, wb, xlapp. That's reverse order, right?

Comment: All I can say is, that the sequence I've listed has worked for an application that ran unattended every night literally for years. So I would think you should try using that _exactly_ as is.